# MsgBox Yes/No Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, msgbox

I have a `Yes/No MsgBox`in my VBA script that returns a question for the user to answer. Whenever the "Yes" or "No" buttons are pressed, besides the script running its respective code, another `MsgBox` with the numbers "6" or "7" pops up. How do I disable this second `MsgBox`?

Here's my code:

```
Dim question As Integer
question = MsgBox("Unfortunately, the Database has no sources regarding " & Category & " in " & country & ". Would you like to broaden your search and see all sources regarding " & country & "?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Empty Sheet")

MsgBox question

If question = vbYes Then
    Sheets("Results").Range("D6").ClearContents
    Sheets("Results").Range("D7").ClearContents
    Category = Sheets("Results").Range("D6").Value
Else
    Sheets("Results").Range("D5").ClearContents
    Sheets("Results").Range("D6").ClearContents
    Sheets("Results").Range("D7").ClearContents
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Well, you call `MsgBox` twice, don't you?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Delete `MsgBox question`

Comment: `question = "Unfortunately, the Database has no sources regarding " & Category & " in " & country & ". Would you like to broaden your search and see all sources regarding " & country & "?."` would suffice

Comment: One way to find errors like these is to run your code [line by line](http://www.automateexcel.com/vba/run-macro-line-by-line).  This is a powerful technical that is worth mastering.  It will help you understand what the individual parts of your VBA are up to.

Comment: This is a very helpful tip. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `MsgBox` function returns a `vbMsgBoxResult` value, which is an enum (and should be a `Long` integer, not an `Integer`).

You're calling it twice:

> ```
> Dim question As Integer
> question = MsgBox("Unfortunately, the Database has no sources regarding " & Category & " in " & country & ". Would you like to broaden your search and see all sources regarding " & country & "?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Empty Sheet")
>
> MsgBox question
> ```

Once to assign `question`, and once to display `question` - which at that point is going to contain either `vbYes` (6) or `vbNo` (7).

[image]

I would declare `question As vbMsgBoxResult` to avoid ambiguities and get autocomplete/IntelliSense when you later use it. Actually, `result` or `answer` would be a better identifier - "question" sounds like *the question itself*, not the user's response.

Answer (score 8):

just use

```
question = "Unfortunately, the Database has no sources regarding " & Category & " in " & country & ". Would you like to broaden your search and see all sources regarding " & country & "?."
```

would be enough.

In addition the if function can be

```
If Msgbox(Question) = vbYes then 
    ...
End If
```

Don't call MsgBox twice

Comment: Yup. There's actually no need to have a variable for the return value if it's only going to be used once.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `MsgBox question`. This is unnecessarily creating a second message box populated with the value of question (6 or 7 depending on whether you chose yes or no, as eg vbYes has the return value 6).